# Combine Mockito VerificationModes with JUnit Parameterized Tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

**Starting Point**
I wanted to unit-test a class that basically doesn't create an output itself, but modifies an object that it receives. To be precise: it delegates to a service class, that creates an image that is appended to the object's `imageList`:

```
public class Class {
 //field declarations ...

 public Class(@Autowired Service service){
  this.service = service;
 }

 public Object process(Object object){
  //determine property here ...

  if(property == optionA){
   //the service will add the new image A to a list in object
   this.service.createImageA(object);
  } else if(property == optionB){
   //the service will add the new image B to a list in object
   this.service.createImageB(object);
  }

  //object will be returned, with or without a new image
  return object;
 }
}
```

**The Work So Far**
The best way - in my opinion - to test this class is:

1. to check if the product returned is the same as the one assigned to the `process` method
2. check how often both `service`methods were invoked (`service` is mocked with Mockito, of course ;) )

Now I would like to combine this with JUnit's ability to create Parameterized tests. Something analogous to:

```
@Parameters
public static List<Object[]> parameters() {
 return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
            {optionA, Mockito.times(1), Mockito.never()},
            {optionB, Mockito.never(), Mockito.times(1)},
            {optionC, Mockito.never(), Mockito.never()},
 });
}
```

**Question**
 1. Is it possible to pass static functions within a parameterized test?
 2. Are there special reasons not to do this?
 3. Any known alternatives?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to pass static functions? What you store there is the result of the method call, which might work. But what for? You can simply pass the integer. 0 (=never) or 1 (=once) and then call it with `Mockito.times( myInteger );`

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz yep, that's true. Still I would like to know if it's actually possible to pass methods as test parameters. Maybe my chosen example isn't quite hitting the mark : ) Can you maybe provide some information about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`never` and `times` return [VerificationMode](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/verification/VerificationMode.html) implementations. Though you're right to be wary of the calling semantics, there seem to be [no side effects to VerificationMode creation](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/verification/VerificationModeFactory.java#L25), so you're free to extract your mode to a variable and pass it in.

Beware, however, that VerificationMode implementations might be stateful (I haven't had a chance to dig deeply), so reusing instances may cause bizarre errors.

As Florian Schaetz mentioned above, you may instead choose to pass integers: `never` is simply an alias for `times(0)`, so you can pass the number of expected invocations (0 or 1) as a JUnit parameter and then call `times(parameter)` in your test without worrying about state or side effects.

---

**As of Java 8, you *can* use [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) or [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to pass code as data between fuunctions**, but the result may not be easy to read or maintain, especially with the cast required to keep a method reference in an `Object[]`:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class LambdaParameters {

  public static Integer toot() { return 0; }
  public static Integer whistle() { return 1; }
  public static Integer plunk() { return 2; }
  public static Integer boom() { return 3; }

  private static Supplier<Integer> wrap(Supplier<Integer> methodCall) {
    return methodCall;
  }

  @Parameters public static List<Object[]> parameters() {
    return ImmutableList.of(
      // Java 8 knows that static call "toot" is effectively a Supplier<Integer>...
      new Object[] { (Supplier<Integer>) LambdaParameters::toot, 0 },
      // ...but it won't infer that without the cast...
      new Object[] { (Supplier<Integer>) LambdaParameters::whistle, 1 },
      // ...or without getting the hint through a method like "wrap" above.
      new Object[] { wrap(LambdaParameters::plunk), 2 },
      // Most lambda expressions are for calling Runnables, Listeners, Callbacks,
      // and short Functions or Predicates, so the casts there aren't necesssary.

      // You can use this syntax for compact lambda functions too.
      new Object[] { wrap(() -> 3), 3 },

      // All of these are effectively anonymous inner classes as you might see
      // in previous versions of Java.
      new Object[] { new Supplier<Integer>() { @Override public Integer get() { return LambdaParameters.boom(); }}, 3 }
    );
  }

  private Supplier<Integer> supplier;
  private Integer integer;

  public LambdaParameters(Supplier<Integer> supplier, Integer integer) {
    this.supplier = supplier;
    this.integer = integer;
  }

  @Test public void supplierSuppliesExpectedInteger() {
    assertEquals(integer, supplier.get());
  }
}
```

Whether this is worth the extra logic depends entirely on how many parameters you have, how many tests you have, and whether there are any alternatives (as there are for VerificationMode).

Comment: It's true that this is probably the best solution for this. Still I'm wondering if there is actually the possibility to pass functions as JUnit test parameters. You're quite experienced with Mockito (and unit testing in general, I guess :) ), so maybe you know some sources I could take into consideration (doesn't need to be limited to JUnit).

Comment: You cannot use functions as a parameter in Java. Period. What you can do of course is use a wrapper that calls a function as a parameter. Or the name of the method as a paramter which then is called via reflection. But you simply cannot give the function itself as a parameter and then somehow call it.

Comment: You can absolutely use functions as parameters in Java 8, as in the example I edited in above. Technically this solution still uses wrappers, but because Java generates the wrapper it's probably the answer you're looking for, even if it's probably not the best solution for your problem.